# Possible to set message box buttons to not have a default button focus?

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

Is it possible to set it so there is no default button focus when a messagebox appears? This way, the message box will force the user to select Yes or No with a mouse. The MessageBoxDefaultButton (as seen below) only allows for the changing of the default button and does not give the option to select none.

```
MsgBox("continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Do you want to continue?", MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Write your own simple form window and you can directly control all of the button behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I was planning to do, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier fix first.

Comment: Don't forget to trap keyboard input, otherwise the user can just tab over to a button hit it without the mouse.

Comment: @asawyer easier yet set `Button.TabStop = False`

Answer (score 2):

Its quiet easy to set default button on Vb.net Msgbox by combining MsgBoxStyle (MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2) :

```
MsgBox("Er. Mayank Nainwal", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2, "Default Button is NO ?")

    If MsgBox("Er. Mayank Nainwal", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2, "Default Button is NO ?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        '' Your Code 
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio (VB, 16.8.4) - If you need the Information symbol together with focus on the Yes button try this:-

```
MsgBox("Your message", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton1, "The MsgBox title")
```

Comment: No sure why you had to edit my original code DuDa, if you copy and paste my original code into Visual Studio (VB) 2019 it works works just fine. Please try it..